Generator names randomly between 3-10 char but same character
Can someone please help me with coding the following in a single method: I need to randomaly generate 10 names between 3 and 10 characters long but each name only contains a single character e.g aaa, nnnnn etc;
I have the following code:
public static void task() {
    // Chose Random character from below String
    final String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    // Variable for max and min length of string
    final int max = 10;
    final int min = 3;

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        // Random select of length of the String
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(alpha);
        Random theGeneratorForLength = new Random();
        int aLengthVariable = (theGeneratorForLength.nextInt(max - min) + min);
        char alphaString = alpha.charAt(aLengthVariable);
        sb.append(alphaString);
        System.out.println("String " + (n + 1) + " :" + alphaString + aLengthVariable);
    }

So I have alphaString which returns me a single chracter and then aLengthVariable which returns me the required lengths. Example output:
String 1 :f5
String 2 :d3
String 3 :h7
String 4 :h7
String 5 :d3
String 6 :i8
String 7 :j9
String 8 :i8
String 9 :j9
String 10 :e4

i am just struggling now to get the output to be the character repeated number of times it says so String 1 output would  be fffff, String 2 ddd and so on.

Your code is incomplete. Please fix that. But also, remember to reduce your code to what matters: if your question is "how do I turn a string that's a letter and a number into a new string that's that letter repeated as many times as the number incidates", then ask that, and focus on just the code for that. How you got the original letter+number string is basically irrelevant to that question. And then most important of course: did you already search specifically for that problem?

check the repeat() method of String -- something like alpha.substring(letter, letter+1).repeat(aLengthVariable) where letter is the random index of the letter to select, use the same Random to get it

Does this answer your question? What is the easiest way to generate a String of n repeated characters?

Problem one, you are re-initializing your Random on every loop iteration. That resets the seed which is based on time by default. On a modern system, you're likely to get the same seed over and over again. Declare it once before the loop.
Second, you want to repeat the String a certain (random) number of times - and that is your count. You are using that as a random index into your "symbol table". Use the table length instead. Like,
public static void task() {
    // Chose Random character from below String
    final String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    // Variable for max and min length of string
    final int max = 10;
    final int min = 3;

    Random rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        // Random select a "character" s.
        String s = String.valueOf(alpha.charAt(rand.nextInt(alpha.length())));
        // Random number of characters.
        int count = rand.nextInt(max - min) + min; 
        System.out.println("String " + (n + 1) + " :" + s.repeat(count));
    }
}


Thank you for explaining - I am very new to Java so trying to slowly understand and work through.

I would make your code as reusable and extensible as possible. It should do one obvious thing and should be self-documenting, so not task() but something like  getRandomMonoCharString(). Make a method that returns what you want. What is likely to change, or what would be good to have flexibility in it? Well the obvious thing is the length of the string, so maybe something like:
    public static String getRandomMonoCharString(int minLenInc, int maxLenExc) {
        Random rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        char randChar = (char)(rand.nextInt(26) + 'a');
        int randLength = rand.nextInt(minLenInc, maxLenExc);
        char[] a = new char[randLength];
        Arrays.fill(a, randChar);
        return new String(a);
    }


The Answers by Elliott Frisch and by g00se offer good advice. Here are a few more tips.
Naming constants
Per Java conventions, constants are named in all uppercase.
final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
final int MAX = 10;
final int MIN = 3;

ThreadLocalRandom
Using ThreadLocalRandom as your random number generator means you need not hold a reference to it, as you are are not instantiating. Just call ThreadLocalRandom.current() where needed.
Also, ThreadLocalRandom offers more convenient methods for generating a value, without doing math.
int repetition = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( MIN , MAX ) ;

Code points, not char
The char type has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, char is physically incapable of representing most characters.
Make a habit of using code point integer numbers when you need to work with individual characters.
final int[] codePointsOfAlphabet = ALPHABET.codePoints().toArray() ;

Grab one character at random.
int randomIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 0 , codePointsOfAlphabet.length ) ;
int randomCodePoint = codePointsOfAlphabet[ randomIndex ] ;
String singleCharacter = Character.toString( randomCodePoint ) ;

String#repeat
The String class offers a handy repeat method to multiply text.
String result = singleCharacter.repeat( repetition ) ;

